# change the value of object using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object as,

```
var obj = [ 
            {
              "name": "a",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "b",
              "value": "2"
            },
            {
              "name": "c",
              "value": "3"
            }
          ]
```

I have a large object with more than 50 values.
how can I change the `value` key using its `name`
and what is the best looping technique for this.

I tried `for loop` for this like,

```
    for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if(obj[i].name == "b") {
            // some other functionality
            obj[i].value = "some_value";
        }
    }
```

But, it takes long time and sometimes `for loop` goes for next turn before `if condition` is executed.

Please explain how to solve it or is there any other looping technique

Comment: You dont have an object,  but it is an array of objects

Comment: first you should put `var` before `i = 0` to make sure that `i` is not global. You could also add a `break`in the block condition if you don't have other value to change

Comment: _"and sometimes for loop goes for next turn before if condition is executed."_ What? Is your code asynchronous?

Comment: Actually its a code of external plugin in cordova project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use forEach , but as far your hitting the performance its not best ,

you can use map but native for loop is fastest compared to map too

https://jsperf.com/native-map-versus-array-looping

Map , which runs on the each item of the array and return the new array

```
obj.map(function(item){
  if(item.name === "b"){
      item.value = "some_value"
   }
 return item;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Map is your friend!

```
var obj = [ 
  { "name": "a", "value": "1" },
  { "name": "b", "value": "2" },
  { "name": "c", "value": "3" }
];

var newObj = obj.map((elm) => {
  if(elm.name === "b") elm.value = "some value";
  return elm;
});
```

Is this something like what you were looking for?

Comment: use `obj.map(function(elm)` instead of `obj.map((elm)`. Then only it worked for me.

Comment: I missed out the => in the short arrow function syntax. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var obj = [ 
    {
      "name": "a",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "c",
      "value": "3"
    }
  ]

  for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
      if(obj[i].name === "b") {
        console.log(obj[i].name);
        // some other functionality
        obj[i].value = "some_value";
      }
    })(i);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you had was quite ok. As one of the comments stated, there was a mistake in the IF-statement which prevented it from being triggered.

I am not sure theres a faster way to proces the JSON object than the way you did. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nou41hm6/1/) with some small changes.

```
function ReplaceValue(name, val) {
    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].name == name) {
      // some other functionality
      obj[i].value = val;
      break;
    }
  }
    alert(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In lodash you can do something like this:

`

```
var obj = [ 
            {
              "name": "a",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "b",
              "value": "2"
            },
            {
              "name": "c",
              "value": "3"
            }
          ];        
 _.transform(arr, function(r, n){
   if(n.name == 'b'){
     r.push({name: n.name, value: 'some value'})}
   else{
     r.push(n)
   }
  })
```

`